# Sistema de logging PHP

Tags: php

Queria registar tudo o que acontece no meu site, desde logins, criação de registos (insert), atualização e eliminação. 
Parecido com isso:

> [14-05-2016 17:53] Utilizador andre fez login com IP: 111.111.111.111
>   [14-05-2016 17:54] Utilizador andre eliminou o cliente com ID 2
>   [14-05-2016 17:55] Utilizador andre criou o cliente com ID 3

Criei um script em php para escrever os registos num ficheiro `log.log` 
Conteúdo do ficheiro `regista.php`

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Lisbon'); $cache_new = date("\[d-m-Y H:i\] ");
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

$cache_new .= $_GET['q']; 

$file = "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pap\\registos\\log.log"; 
$cache_new .= "\n";
$handle = fopen($file, "r+") or die ();
$len = strlen($cache_new);
$final_len = filesize($file) + $len;
$cache_old = fread($handle, $len);
rewind($handle);
$i = 1;
while (ftell($handle) < $final_len) {
  fwrite($handle, $cache_new);
  $cache_new = $cache_old;
  $cache_old = fread($handle, $len);
  fseek($handle, $i * $len);
  $i++;
}
?>
```

Se eu for ao `http://meusite/registo/regista.php?q=Utilizador fez login` ele vai registar no ficheiro. 
Mas eu queria automático, por exemplo o ficheiro `eliminar.php`, após o script eliminar o cliente da base de dados vai registar no log.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://omeusite/registos/regista.php?q=Utilizador fez login");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

Ao colocar isso no `eliminar.php`, após executar a query na base de dados a página fica extremamente lenta e não regista a entrada.
Que fiz de errado?

Comment: Fazer uma requisição externa não é o jeito adequado. Seria melhor gravar no DB diretamente, ou num arquivo intermediário. Aliás, `curl` em boa parte dos casos em que é usado, não é a melhor solução.

Comment: @Bacco sabe de alguma alternativa sem recorrer à base de dados?

Comment: Qual seria o problema da base de dados? lembre-se que você pode usar uma diferente da usada na aplicação, e até externa, se é pra auditoria. No pior dos casos, se preferir, você pode deixar essa parte do curl depois da página ser enviada para o cliente, e dar um flush no buffer. vai continuar com a demora da requisição, mas o usuário não vai ser afetado.

Comment: E precisa testar esse curl seu separado, pois pode ter algum erro no endereço e por isso ele demora e não registra.

Comment: Vou mudar para guardar os registos na base de dados.

Comment: Obrigado mesmo assim @Bacco

Comment: De qq forma, teste o curl separado, e assim que conseguir que ele funcione, jogue no final da página, quem sabe muda algo, ao menos para localizar o problema. O DB ainda me parece mais prático pro seu caso.